how to change viewPort width of big screens to 1280px in react
I am currently utilizing HTML2Canvas and jsPDF to export a PDF document. When the browser viewport width is 1280 pixels, the resulting PDF displays the UI as intended. However, I have encountered an issue where the UI becomes distorted when viewPort is greater than 1280px. I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this matter to ensure the PDF maintains its intended appearance across all screen sizes.
here's my code
  const pdfExport = async (sections: any[]) => { 
dispatch(setIsexporting(true));
let doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm");
let metaTag = document.getElementById('viewport');
  metaTag?.setAttribute("content", "width=1280");

const pageHeight = 292; // Height of the page

for (let index = 0; index < sections.length; index++) {
  const section = sections[index];
  const divToPrint = section.current;
  // Check if the section's height is greater than 10 pixels
  if (divToPrint.clientHeight > 20) {
    await html2canvas(divToPrint).then((canvas) => {
      let imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
      let imgWidth = 206; // Reduced width to accommodate padding

      let imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;
      let positionX = 2; // Padding from left side
      let positionY = 2; // Padding from top

      // Add a new page if it's not the first section
      if (index > 0) {
        doc.addPage();
      }

      // Adding page image
      doc.addImage(
        imgData,
        "PNG",
        positionX,
        positionY,
        imgWidth,
        imgHeight
      );

      // Calculate remaining space after adding the image
      let remainingSpace = pageHeight - (positionY + imgHeight) + 4;

      // If there is remaining space, fill it with a background color
      if (remainingSpace > 0) {
        doc.setFillColor(
          247,
          248,
          250
        );
        doc.rect(
          positionX,
          positionY + imgHeight,
          imgWidth,
          remainingSpace,
          "F"
        );
      }

      // gray border with padding
      doc.setDrawColor(247, 248, 250);
      doc.setLineWidth(5);
      doc.rect(0, 0, 210, 298);

      if (index === sections.length - 1) {
        doc.save("exhibitors_statistics.pdf");
        let metaTag = document.getElementById('viewport');
          metaTag?.setAttribute(
            "content",
            "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
          );
      }
    });
  }
}
dispatch(setIsexporting(false));
};

for small devices its changes the viewport to 1280  but on big screen i dont know why but its not  working..

Without having spent a lot of time looking at your code, couldn't you just open a new window on click with a predefined size and then export from that window? Of export from a (hidden) iframe?

@SvenvandeScheur I am currently using html2canvas to capture screenshots of content that is divided into different sections, using a hidden iframe will result in content being cut off. I am looking for a solution to ensure that the entire content is captured seamlessly.
